# Объяснение как добавить фрагменты (или что это) программно

Tags: android, android-fragment

Вопрос в следующем: Увидел уже не один раз, как например в записных книжках, после сохранения какого-то значения на главном экране появляется фрагмент с этим значением, и при нажатии на него его можно форматировать. Примеры приведу в изображениях (Приложение Google Keep). Это фрагменты или что это?

[image: Главная страница]

[image: Редактор выбраного]

Answer (score 0):

Ну если взять Google Keep то там обычный `RecyclerView` с `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. При клике на любой элемент открывается новое `activity/fragment`. Внутри это редактируется, а при возврате в `RecyclerView` просто подгружаются обновленные данные.

Как вернуть обновленные данные? Могу дать пару вариантов:

- При открытии элемента для редактирования сохранять данные в репозиторий, а при возврате на предыдущий экран со списком просто заново оттуда из тянуть. Пожалуй это самый простой и правильный путь.
- Вы так же можете создать `ViewModel` которая будет жить все время пока жив экран списка и экран деталей заметки. И в ней хранить данные. Этот способ работает на основе паттерна `Observer` поэтому данные будут сами обновляться по мере их изменения.
- Если открывать по клику на элемент `activity` (`fragment` тоже можно, но там немного проблемнее) то можно использовать метод `onActivityResult()` и в нем возвращать измененный результат и обновлять список. Но я бы не стал использовать этот способ.

Можно придумать и другие пути, но это уже зависит от конкретной реализации.

**UPD:**

Конечно никто не мешает вам создать подобный экран на фрагментах. Вы можете создать грубо говоря `ScrollView` в который просто добавлять новые фрагменты. Но нужно ли это здесь? Думаю нет. Хотя есть ситуации когда это будет неплохим решением. Например если у вас будет список списков то порой внутренние списки обрабатывать легче во фрагменте чем в том же `RecyclerView`. Или если в каждом элементе списка хранится сложная логика, тогда вы так же можете использовать список на основе фрагментов и `ScrollView`